# Pointer to another pointer (levels of indirections)?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

I have one inquiry. This topic is well-known by many, but I have came across it just recently and I have maybe basic question.

On [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/passing-structures), we can read about memory indirection.

From that site, I have an understanding that one level of undirection matches reference types, that is variable of reference type has just a pointer to somewhere in memory, where object is allocated. That is how I understood level of indirectrion.

**Question**: Is this understanding correct?

**If no**, what would be the correct understanidng? And what would be two level of inderection?

**If yes**, what would be the second level of indirection? Would it be pointer to another pointer? Is that so?

Comment: A pointer is itself just a variable (or object allocated at some location in memory). Thus a second level of indirection is simply a pointer to an object that happens to be a pointer to some other object. I think you've mostly got it.

Comment: Is is like passing the water bucket from hand to hand. Number of people is the number of indirection. https://www.electrosmash.com/images/tech/mn3007/fire-bucket-brigade.jpg

Comment: See: [What does “level of indirection” mean in David Wheeler's aphorism?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18003704/880990)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the examples provided for a second level of indirection. In C# a signature like this:

```
DoWork(ref MyType x)
```

requires a reference to a reference type. Which is equivalent (as stated in the article you linked) to an unmanaged signature of

```
DoWork(MyType** x);
```

So a pointer to a pointer.

Your understanding is correct - a reference type provides at least one level of indirection, as it's a pointer to an object. A `ref MyType x` is a reference to a reference type, so it's a pointer to a pointer to an object, and thus a second level of indirection.