# Uses of assigning a class to a variable in Python

Tags: python

Is there any good reason why one would assign a class to a variable as shown in the code below ? What are some useful/interesting things one can do thanks to that mechanic ?

```
class foo:

    # Some initialization stuff
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    # Some methods and other stuff

myVar = foo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case I've seen most often in production code is dependency injection or "compile-time" configuration.

For example, I may have some classes that implement some strategy or command, but I don't have the details for the constructor yet.

```
class StrategyOne:...
class StrategyTwo:...

def my_func(vars, Strategy):
    x = some_calculation(vars)
    st = Strategy(x)
```

An example of using this as configuration can be seen in the [django-rest-framework docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include)

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'account_name', 'users', 'created')
```

I think most uses cases fall into the principle of "I don't want to couple  to this *particular* class". [Another level of indirection and all.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003544/what-does-level-of-indirection-mean-in-david-wheelers-aphorism)

Take the [type checking example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54910795/633094) for instance. The loop over the collection of types `[x for x in lst if isinstance(x, types)]` does not depend on any particular types and is thus decoupled from the contents of the list of types.

Answer (score 2):

One important use-case certainly is for type checking or filtering:

```
class Foo:
    pass

lst = ["bla", 42, Foo()]
types = (str, Foo)
filtered = [x for x in lst if isinstance(x, types)]
# ['bla', <__main__.Foo at 0x7fa3422aa668>]
```

Another might be for dynamically creating instances of some class, e.g. with `defaultdict`.

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(Bar)
for x, y in [(1,1), (1,2), (2,3), (2,4)]:
    d[x].value += y
print(d[1].value) # 3
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities. One could be if you have multiple classes, and you want to access the same attribute from all of them.

For example:

```
classes = [Class1, Class2, Class3]

for c in classes:
    print(c.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason I can think of is that you will call the constructor multiple times. So, instead of

```
x1 = foo()
x2 = foo()
x3 = foo()
```

you can write

```
cls = foo
x1 = cls()
x2 = cls()
x3 = cls()
```

So, you can only change `cls=foo` with `cls=bar`, and the rest needs no changes.

However, this is only appropriate for code snippets, just to try something quickly. If you actually need to do something multiple times, write a function.